# String.empty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In .NET, I tend to use [String.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) when I want to use an empty string.

I would like to add this functionality to the `String` object in JavaScript.

My first thought was something like this:

```
if(!String.empty){
    String.empty = '';
}
```

I suppose this is the right way to go?

The reason that I'm asking is because I want to know if I should involve the `String.prototype`. But it feels wrong since this has nothing to do with actually instantiating a `new String()`. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all I know, you are completely right. The String.prototype would give an 'empty' property to all your strings, but that is clearly not what you want. You could even omit the 'if' part and just write

```
String.empty = '';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The if part is just to make sure I don't overwrite someone else's implementation. Probably a bit overkill in this case

Answer (score 0):

I do always like this:

```
var str = $.trim(' string ');
if(str){
   // not empty
 }else{
   // empty
 }
```